# MonoTouch App Crash

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

Hi i'm experiencing some crashes on my mono touch Application that happens on different screens of the application, on this app i have some Tasks Running on the background could be that the cause, what i should do to figure out the problems?

```
0   iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00a848f1 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 244
1   iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00a75c6d mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 172
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34bbe7ed _sigtramp + 48
3   UIKit                               0x3072de0f -[UIAlertView(Private) _popoutAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 854
4   UIKit                               0x305e3aab -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 470
5   UIKit                               0x305e93d5 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 52
6   QuartzCore                          0x35d6fc2f _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 202
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3464bee7 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 194
8   CoreFoundation                      0x3746d2ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1268
9   CoreFoundation                      0x373f04a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
10  CoreFoundation                      0x373f036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
11  GraphicsServices                    0x375e9439 GSEventRunModal + 136
12  UIKit                               0x305fccd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
13  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x0012fdec wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 240
14  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x004689b0 iShowRoomIPAD_Application_Main_string__ + 152
15  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00946a6c wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
16  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00a771f7 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1054
17  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00ae78e7 mono_runtime_invoke + 90
18  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00aea527 mono_runtime_exec_main + 306
19  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00aed87f mono_runtime_run_main + 482
20  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00a7a25f mono_jit_exec + 94
21  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00a74a3b main + 2166
22  iShowRoomIPAD                       0x00002998 start + 40
```

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

## used by your application.

Comment: you just clean your solution and Rebuild it hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Which MonoTouch, MonoDevelop, iOS and SDK version is installed?

Answer (score 1):

This error sometimes indicates that you disposed (freed) C# wrappers for native objects still in use. For example, if you dispose an animation instance that is still active, or a viewcontroller from one of its event handlers.

The bad thing about this exception it may not happen instantly after you freed an object. It may take some time app to fail. So, check your app for such situations.